# A single cmd app to support multiple compression format

Tags: linux, command-line, file-compression

As you know by default there is one program (command) for each compression format and unfortunately, some of them use a different command for data extraction.

I would like to memorize a single app that supports common compression/archiving formats with a single unified command syntax. What is your suggested program?

Comment: write a shell script that uses `file` to detect file type and then run appropriate file type specific utility....

Comment: I'm not using any such programm, but at least in Ubuntu/Mint I can find `atool`, `dtrx`, `patool` … `apt-cache search` is your friend on those systems :)

Comment: @Izzy The main concern of the question is cmd. If you have to memorise a command better to learn the most versatile tool.

Comment: Thanks, @PHPst – I've fixed my above comment. Did you take a look at the 3 tools I've mentioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to support *all* compression formats. Because **not every format is known publicly**, and even within famous formats like zip and rar there are variants that may not be known or supported<sup>2</sup> (have you ever heard of [`*.zipx`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)))? It's produced by winzip but [rarely any other tools can open it](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/5d5f57e2/?limit=25&page=0)). Moreover **some formats don't allow you to embed in other tools**<sup>1</sup>

But if you just want to be able to work with *most common file formats* then [7z](https://www.7-zip.org/7z.html) and it's [`p7zip` Linux counterpart](https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/) are probably the best solutions. It's not commonly used in Linux land like on Windows, but it does support a single syntax for all formats: `7z a` to compress and `7z x` to decompress

However of course it has some quirks like mentioned above

- <sup>1</sup> 7z can decompress most common file types including *.rar but it can't compress into rar because of licensing reasons
- <sup>2</sup> It doesn't support all zip and rar formats

> ### Why can't 7-Zip open some ZIP archives?
>
> In 99% of these cases it means that the archive contains incorrect headers. Other ZIP programs can open some archives with incorrect headers, since these programs just ignore errors.
>
> If you have such archive, please don't call the 7-Zip developers about it. Instead try to find the program that was used to create the archive and inform the developers of that program that their software is not ZIP-compatible.
>
> There are also some ZIP archives that were encoded with methods unsupported by 7-Zip, for example, WAVPack (WinZip).
>
> ### Why can't 7-Zip open some RAR archives?
>
> 7-Zip 9.20 supports RAR 2/3/4 formats only and doesn't support RAR5 archives. But latest versions of 7-Zip supports RAR5 archives.
>
> https://www.7-zip.org/faq.html

An important note: [*7-zip does not store the owner/group of the file*](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-use-7zip-file-archiver-on-ubuntu-linux/) so you have to pass through `tar` first if you really need to store those information.

---

[Winrar](https://www.rarlab.com/) is also a good solution, which supports [RAR, ZIP, CAB, ARJ, LZH, TAR, GZ, BZ2, ACE, UUE, JAR, ISO, 7Z, XZ, Z](https://www.rarlab.com/otherfmt.htm). Unfortunately previously the command prompt version was free, but now it has also become trial software. If you can live with [the "infinite" trial period](https://youtu.be/fTgZRVVr3_Y) it's also worth a try

---

But 7z and winrar are not the compression softwares that *support the most formats*. According to [Wikipedia with a list of 19 formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_archivers#Archive_format_support) we have the following top softwares with their supported formats

- Writing:

  - [Ark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_(software)): 16/19
  - BulkZip, [PeaZip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PeaZip), [StuffIt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StuffIt), [The Unarchiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unarchiver): 14/19
  - [ALZip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALZip), [PowerArchiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerArchiver): 13/19
- Reading:

  - [PowerArchiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerArchiver): 10/19
  - [PeaZip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PeaZip), [Archive Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_Manager), [WinAce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinAce): 9/19

Of course the above list is not absolutely correct, because there are a lot more formats which are not included. Most archivers support significantly more than those 19 format. For example [PeaZip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PeaZip) *"supports 188 file extensions (as of version 6.0.0)"*, and [BulkZip](https://download.cnet.com/BulkZip-File-Compressor/3000-2250_4-76399178.html) claims to support these formats:

> - Compression: Bulk, 7z, Arc, Nz, Pja, Tar, Zip, Zpaq
> - Extraction: 7z, Ace, Bulk, Apk, Arc, Arj, Bz2, Ear, Cab, Cb7, Cba, Cbr, Cbt, Cbz, Chm, Cramfs, Dmg, Gz, Img, Ipa, Iso, Jar, Lha, Lzh, Lzma, Nz, Pja, Rar, Rar5, Tar, Tbz, Tgz, Txz, Uha, Uue, War, Wim, Xz, Z, Zip, Zipx, Zpaq

Note that extension and format are different. Some extensions can contain various formats